# Find $P(X ≤ 2)$ and $E(X)$.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a game in which you rolls a single die until you accumulates a total of at least four dots. Let $X$ denote the number of rolls needed. Find $P(X \leq 2)$ and $E(X)$.

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone can provide a hint or answer that is based on your work. Such hints or answers are often more useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think that for $E(X)$ we will need the probability distribution function of $X$. Note that $X$ can only take on the values $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$.  We want to find $\Pr(X=k)$ for $k=1,2,3,4$. That will be enough to answer both questions.

We first deal with the two easiest cases.

Case $k=1$: The game ends in one toss if we get a $4$, $5$, or $6$ on that toss. This has probability $\frac{3}{6}$.

Case $k=4$: This case happens if we get $1$ on each of the first three tosses. That has probability $\frac{1}{6^3}$.

Next we deal with the case $k=3$. We get $X=3$ if we get $1,1$ in the first $2$ tosses, and $2$ or more on the next, **or** $1,2$ in the first two tosses, or $2,1$. The probability is $\frac{1}{6^2}\cdot\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}$.

For the case $k=2$, note that the probabilities of the four cases must add up to $1$, so if we know three of them we know the fourth. But it might be useful to make a separate calculation, as a check, or for practice. We have $X=2$ if we get $1$ on the first toss, and $\ge 3$ on the second, **or** $2$ on the first toss, and $\ge 2$ on the second, **or** $3$ on the firat toss.

**Added:** So $\Pr(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, $\Pr(X=4)=\frac{1}{216}$ and $\Pr(X=3)=\frac{17}{216}$. By either of the calculations in the answer above, we have $\Pr(X=2)=\frac{5}{12}$.

It follows that $\Pr(X\le 2)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{12}$.

It also follows that
$$E(X)=1\cdot \frac{1}{2}+2\cdot\frac{5}{12}+3\cdot \frac{17}{216}+4\cdot\frac{1}{216}.$$
One is presumably expected to simplify the two answers.

Comment: could you please more elaborate the answer sir? I mean upto the solution?

Comment: @Hani: Calculations done, apart from simplifications.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: i have another question sir

Comment: I cannot answer it if I do not know what the question is! And it can be difficult to answer a question in a comment. If you have a new question, I suggest you ask it, and give information about what you have tried, so that the question will not be quickly closed.

Comment: No sir you got it wrong. Actually its not related to that question.I type the question here

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate all possible outcomes: (assuming 6 faced die)

```
X = 4
```

1,1,1,(any) = 6 possible outcomes

```
x = 3
```

1,1,(2 or higher) = 5

1,2,(any) = 6

2,1,(any) = 6

```
X = 2
```

1,3 = 1

1,{4,5,6} = 3

2,{3,4,5,6} = 4

3,(any) = 6

```
X = 1
```

{4,5,6} = 3

```
P(X<=2) = (6+4+3+1+3)/40

E(X) = (3/40)*1 + (14/40)*2 + (17/40)*3 + (6/40)*4
```

First answer I ever wrote, hope it helps.

Comment: Not all these outcomes have the same probability.  Clearly $P(X \le 2)$ must be greater than $\frac 12$, because half the time you get at least four dots on the first roll.